# 26 of 99 Haskell problems - why the result contains multiple lists with the same head?

Tags: haskell, recursion, combinations, list-comprehension

I am trying to figure out how one of the solutions to problem 26 of [99 Haskell problems](https://wiki.haskell.org/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems) works. The solution is as follows:

```
combination :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combination 0 _ = [ [] ]
combination i xs = [ y:ys | y:xs' <- tails xs, ys <- combination (i-1) xs']
```

I can't understand how it is possible that there will be more than one list with the same head. To me the `y` part in `y:ys` that will be produced from using `tails xs` can be used only to compose one list.

Example:

```
combination 2 [1,2,3]
```

First we take the `y` part from `tails xs`, which gives us three lists: `[1,(not known yet)]`, `[2,(not known yet)]`, `[3,(not known yet)]`. So how come at the end we get multiple results with 1 as the head?

I also can't grasp why the list `[3]` won't be in the result? It certainly will appear as a head in one of the lists produced by `tails xs`. I didn't want to raise this concern in a separate question - I hope that's fine.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I've added an answer that focuses more on why the tails is there (for picking the first element for our combination)

Comment: You may want to experiment with this: `[ y:ys | y<-[1] , ys<-[[2],[3],[4]] ]`. Here there is only one possible value for `y`, but this comprehension will produce three lists (of lists), not just one.

Comment: @chi Great point. That's what I was missing (well, not only that, but it was my main concern).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehensions define *nested loops*, in a way. Thus, in the definition

```
combinations n xs =
```

we can read the code

```
        [ y:ys | y:t <- tails xs, ys <- combinations (n-1) t]
```

as

```
        for each (y:t) in (tails xs)
            for each ys in (combinations (n-1) t) 
                produce (y:ys) as a new element of the resulting list
```

In other words, to pick `n` elements from a list means to pick some element, and `n-1` elements after it in the list.

The non-deterministic nature of this definition is represented by producing a list of *all* the possible solutions, as the result. We pick the `n-1` elements only *to the right* of the element, to only produce solutions that are *unique* under permutation.

---

Let's take `xs = [1,2,3]` as an example. What does `tails [1,2,3]` produce?

It's `[[1,2,3], [2,3], [3], []]`, of course. Now, that's equivalent to

```
[ r | r <- [[1,2,3], [2,3], [3], []] ]
```

That means, `r` drawn from that list, takes on the values of its elements, consecutively. `r` is an *irrefutable* pattern there; `(y:t)` is a refutable pattern, i.e. it will fail to match the `[]` element:

```
[ (y,t) | (y:t) <- tails [1,2,3]]
  =>  [(1,[2,3]), (2,[3]), (3,[])]
```

So you see, `t` is not *"not known yet"*. It *is* known, it's just the tail of a given list. And when `y` matches with 3, `t` is matched with `[]`.

Moreover,

```
[ (y,q) | (y:t) <- tails [1,2,3], q <- [10,20]]
 =>  [(1,10), (1,20), (2,10), (2,20), (3,10), (3,20)]
```

This is illustrative enough, hopefully, to clear your first question: for each matching `(y:t)` pattern, `q` is drawn from `[10,20]`, i.e. it also takes on the values in the list (here, `[10,20]`) consecutively, for each `y`, as if in a *nested loop*.

---

For your example of `combinations 2 [1,2,3]` we have

```
  combinations 2 [1,2,3]
=
  for each (y,t) in [ (1,[2,3]), (2,[3]), (3,[]) ]
      for each ys in (combinations 1 t)
          produce (y:ys)
=
  for y = 1, t = [2,3]
      for each ys in (combinations 1 [2,3]) produce (1:ys) , and then
  for y = 2, t = [3]
      for each ys in (combinations 1 [3])   produce (2:ys) , and then
  for y = 3, t = []
      for each ys in (combinations 1 [])    produce (3:ys)
```

`combinations 1 []` is `[]`, because `tails []` is `[[]]` and pattern matching `(y:t)` with `[]` as part of generator  `(y:t) <- [[]]` will fail; so no solutions will be produced by the third *`for`* line <sub>(that would have `3` in the solution's head - because there are no more elements to its right to pick the second element from, as we need to pick 2 elements overall; 3 does indeed participate in tails of other solutions, as it well should).</sub>

The second *`for`* line obviously produces just one solution, `[2,3]`. What does the first *`for`* line produce?

```
      for each ys in (combinations 1 [2,3]) produce (1:ys)
```

`combinations 1` takes just one element, so it produces `[2]` and `[3]`; so the first `for` line produces two solutions, `[1,2]` and `[1,3]`. Or in more detail,

```
      combinations 1 [2,3] 
    =
      for y = 2, t = [3]
          for each ys in (combinations 0 [3]) produce (2:ys) , and then
      for y = 3, t = []
          for each ys in (combinations 0 [])  produce (3:ys)
```

and `combinations 0` always produces a single solution that is an empty list (a singleton list with an empty list as its only element, `[ [] ]`, representing a solution of picking 0 elements from a list).

So overall, the list of three solutions is returned, `[[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]`.

Comment: This is a great and detailed answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The core thing to notice here is the *recursive nature of the problem*.

How can we pick `i` items from a list?

- If the list is empty, then there are no combinations. So that's not an interesting case.
- If the list isn't empty - we can either pick the first item for our combination or not

  - If we pick it, we still have to pick `i-1` items from the rest of the list
  - If we do not pick it, we still have to pick `i` items from the rest of the list

Doing:

```
[ y:ys | y:xs' <- tails xs, ys <- combination (i-1) xs']
```

- Look at all the tails of `xs`, that is, **look at all the possibilities for picking the *first* element for our `i` combination**.
- Pick that first element, as explained above we now have `i-1` items, thus, we need to concat that element to the combinations of `i-1` items with the remaining items.